# Перефразирование плана диплома.

Tags: php

Добрых времени суток, хочу попросить у Вас про помощь перефразировать план на более сложный, грамотный план для диплома.

> ГЛАВА 1 АНАЛИЗ АУДИТОРИИ СОЦИАЛЬНЫХ СЕТЕЙ И МЕТОДОВ ПОСТРОЕНИЯ СОЦИАЛЬНЫХ СЕТЕЙ
>   1.1 История развития социальных сетей 
>   1.2 Типы социальных сетей
>   1.3 Аудитория социальных сетей
> ГЛАВА 2 РАЗРАБОТКА ПОРТАЛА.
>   2.1 История и развитие PHP
>   2.2.Становление MySQL 
>   2.3 Создание и распространение разметки HTML и CSS. 
>   2.4 Сравнение PHP с ASP, Perl, сравнение MySQL с Oracle 
> ГЛАВА 3. РАЗРАБОТКА ПОРТАЛА
>   3.1 Алгоритм разработки и блок-схемы.
>   3.2 Алгоритм взаимодействия с БД и блок схемы. 
>   3.3 Разработка дизайна

Comment: - Думаю, что здесь могут скорее прокомментировать что-то готовое, нежели придумывать план для вас.

- Не очень понятен переход от *социальной сети* к *порталу.* Если вы пишите про социальные сети, то и говорите об их разработке. Если же про порталы вообще - то первая глава получается не в тему.

- Если пишите про социальные сети, то добавьте главу, например, о технологиях и технических решениях, которые используются, например, в `Facebook` и `Вконтакте`. Сравните их, тем более, что информации достаточно.

Comment: С Вами можно связаться и проконсультироваться? У меня есть план другой, но мне надо его расшифровать =). Положите?

Comment: @Node_pro Я еще свой диплом не дописал, а вы уже собрались со мной консультироваться :)

Comment: > 2.2.Становление MySQL 

Это `make install` высоким штилем?

Comment: просто о базе mysql, запросы sql ...

Comment: Тема: Разработка web-портала организации социальных групп

Comment: @karmadro4 В вашей манере комментировать явно чувствуется влияние луркмора / хабра :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, может всеже дадите свои контакты. Скайп, isq, mail?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, скорее наоборот, живой великодвачский, который описали в ракоморье, откуда и его почерпнул IT-планктон, который сбигается на швабрушвабр :-) В любом случае, под заголовком *Становление MySQL* я ожидаю увидеть исторический очерк о чуваках, которые, согласно сложившимся предпосылкам, решили развить свободный SQL-сервер, надстройку им в базис...

Comment: ИМХО, для этого есть ваш научный руководитель!

Comment: @Node_pro E-mail есть у меня в профайле.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим, диплом пишется о изменении требований (ожиданий) к веб-сервисам и соответствующие изменения в плане дизайна, архитектуры, программирования. В этом случае вы посвящаете первую главу социальным изменениям. Показываете, что было,  скажем, лет десять назад и есть сейчас. Количество пользователей, характер этих пользователей, модели использования интернета, связь интернета с другими медиа, доступность интернета. См**о**трите в статике и в динамике.

Вторую главу посвящаете тому, как за это же время развивалась технология, дизайн, подходы к веб-разработке. Не в плане истории создания PHP и MySQL, а в плане того, **что** технологии позволяли делать 10 лет назад и **что** позволяют сейчас. Показываете динамику изменений здесь, появление новых инструментов.

Третья глава - связь первой и второй, социальной и технической сторон. Как одно обусловливает на другое. Можно показать подход к разработке веб-сервиса. Было бы красиво сравнить типовой подход к разработке веб-сервиса 10 лет назад и сейчас (скорость разработки, инструменты разработки, паттерны и т.п.)